# Secure shared memory

Tags: ram, webserver

In my Ubuntu deployment script I have written a function to secure shared memory. For a web server it's important to secure the shared memory to tighten up security. Below you can find the code:

```
echo "tmpfs       /dev/shm     tmpfs   tdefaults,noexec,nosuid        0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

When I reboot the web server it gets stuck. I can't see where it goes wrong. Do you have an idea, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless theres's a typo in your question, I think you're options are off.  First, don't specify 'defaults' (or tdefaults, as you have it..  Here's the output of my shm directory taken from `cat /proc/mounts`:

```
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0
```

Note that on my ubuntu (12.10) it is mounted in /run and not /dev, although I doubt that matters.  Try changing your string to

`echo "tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0" >> /etc/fstab`

and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think the /dev/shm matters. I have had problems mounting /dev/shm on 14.04 (Trusty) with noexec. Using /run/shm works flawlessly. e.g.

```
none    /run/shm        tmpfs   rw,nodev,nosuid,noexec  0       0
```