# Securing shared memory in Ubuntu (Linode VPS) renders it useless. Doesn't boot up

Tags: boot, server, mount, upstart, plymouth

Everytime I setup a new VPS, I secure shared memory by adding the following to `/etc/fstab`:

`tmpfs     /dev/shm     tmpfs     defaults,noexec,nosuid     0     0`

Which works as expected on every host, EXCEPT for Linode.

Here is the bootup error I get in Lish:

```
init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (1335) terminated with status 1                              
init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning                                            
init: ureadahead main process (1338) terminated with status 5                                           
init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (1343) terminated with status 1                              
init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning                                            
init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (1350) terminated with status 1                              
init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning                                            
random: nonblocking pool is initialized
```

The VPS is never able to boot after this and thus has to be deleted completely.

Any idea why that might be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `/dev/shm` with `/run/shm`.

For details, see:

http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics

and

[Secure shared memory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256706/secure-shared-memory)